# I/O error during CreateFile (open) operation for file "3050/var/lib/firebird/data/corp". The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: database, firebird, database-replication, symmetricds

I am getting an error *"The system cannot find the path specified"* trying to connect to Firebird 3.0 using SymmetricDS. Here is the error and my root node configuration (engine.name=corp-000).

```
# The class name for the JDBC Driver 
db.driver=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:3050/var/lib/firebird/data/corp
```

Here is the error I am getting

[image]

I tried enabling legacy Authentication as stated in SymmetricDS documentation, but to no avail:

- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-compat-legacyauth.html
- https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.12/html/user-guide.html#_firebird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong JDBC url. Jaybird essentially has two URL formats, one that matches the legacy Firebird URL format, and one that is more in line with standard URLs and the URLs used by other JDBC drivers. Your current URL combines parts of both formats, and as a result it doesn't work, because with the format you used, it will interpret `3050/var/lib/firebird/data/corp` as a filepath (which causes the *"The system cannot find the path specified"* error), not as port 3050 and filepath `/var/lib/firebird/data/corp`.

You need to use either the recommend format

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050//var/lib/firebird/data/corp
```

Note the double slash (`//`) after the port, this is necessary otherwise the path will be interpreted as the relative path `var/lib/...`, which is not what you want.

Or without port (as 3050 is the default):

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost//var/lib/firebird/data/corp
```

Or the legacy format

```
jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:/var/lib/firebird/data/corp
```

Note the slash (`/`) between host and port, and the colon (`:`) after the port.

Or without port (as 3050 is the default):

```
jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:/var/lib/firebird/data/corp
```

See also [JDBC URLs (`java.sql.DriverManager`)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#jdbc-urls-java.sql.drivermanager) in the *Jaybird Frequently Asked Questions*, and [Obtaining connection java.sql.DriverManager](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connection-drivermanager) in the *Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer’s Manual* (though this only documents the recommended URL format).